# How to work with a boolean conditional in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame (df) with an index of dates and 1,000 rows. A row looks like this:

```
SPY           262.408051
shrtAvg       262.861718
signal              True
Name: 2019-03-22 00:00:00, dtype: object
```

I would like to do a calculation to create a new column based on df.signal like this.

```
df['distance'] = if df.signal == True, df.SPY - df.average, df.average = df.SPY
```

But no matter how I try it I always get this error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I have trued .bool, .apply, np.where, and loc to no avail.
Example:

```
`df['distance'] = np.where(df.signal, df.SPY - df.shrtAVG, df.shrtAVG -df.SPY)`
```

My question is how can I create a new column based on a calulation rooted to a boolean check?

Comment: What should this line `df['distance'] = if df.signal == True, df.SPY - df.average, df.average = df.SPY` mean? This isn't valid Python code.

Comment: I tried a pseudo code example. Sorry if it didn't read well. Is this better? If df.signal == True then df.SPY - df.shrtAvg else df.shrtAvg - df.SPY. I hope that is clearer.

Comment: Try `df['distance'] = (df.SPY - df.average).where(df.signal == True, df.average - df.SPY)`. The `== True` can be omitted.

Comment: I will test that tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in two steps using `.loc[]`:

```
df.loc[df.signal==True, 'distance'] = df.SPY - df.shrtAVG
df.loc[df.signal==False, 'distance'] =  df.shrtAVG - df.SPY
```

Or, you can do it in one step using `.apply()`:

```
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.SPY - row.shrtAVG if row.signal==True else row.shrtAVG - row.SPY, axis=1)
```

Comment: I like the two step approach, much easier to read. I have voted your answer up and will accept it after testing it tomorrow. Thanks